# CSRF attack - GET and POST request on same page

Tags: html, ajax, csrf

One web application has a delete button. Once clicked that web application do GET request first which will return POST form with token key.
Asking Yes or No. if yes, resource is deleted.

How I can achieve this for CSRF attack? I can submit first request hidden in iframe but I need that token to submit second POST request.

Ajax fails due to CORS.

So is it even possible on one page

1. Send GET request
2. Parse response and get token
3. Submit POST form with token to trigger CSRF

Answer (score 0):

I think this is essentially the standard protection against CSRF, a token is generated upon page generation (a GET), and it's verified upon submit (POST) that actually changes application state (deletes an object in your case). So conceptually it looks good to me.

The devil is in the details though. How is the token generated (what algorithm and/or random generator is used, how much entropy it has) and how is it then verified? Is it stored somewhere or stateless? When do you generate a new token and when do you reuse an old one? These are some questions that must be taken into account as always when protecting against CSRF.

One special question that comes to mind for your scenario is whether the confirmation page has all the details about what will be done. A simple "Are you sure?" would not be adequate in your case I think.

Comment: After GET, nothing is sent from client side but response contains token generated by server which doesn't obey X-CSRF header. I need to grab that and re-send. We need to just grab source of first GET and find the token